# Compile error with template specialization, default arguments and VS2013

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T &v = T());

template<>
void f<std::string>(const std::string &v)
{
    std::cout << v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f<std::string>(); // Error in VS2013,  OK in VS2012, gcc-4.7
    f<std::string>("Test");   // OK
    f<std::string>(std::string());  //OK
    return 0;
}
```

The latest Visual Studio 2013 compiler gives the following compiler error for the case when the default argument must be used:

```
error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const std::string *' to 'const std::string &'
Reason: cannot convert from 'const std::string *' to 'const std::string'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Visual Studio 2012 and gcc-4.7 compile fine.

Update: As it seems to be a VS2013 bug, are there any temporary workarounds that do not require significant code changes until this is fixed by MS? Bug report was submitted on MS connect.

Comment: [Works also with gcc-4.8.1](http://ideone.com/gmXSor)

Comment: VS2013 is wrong to reject this.  But what's your question?  Or is this just a rant?

Comment: Note: `std::cout << v;` throws an error in VS2012: it needs to be `std::cout << v.c_str();`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see this kind of problems with template functions, I try to switch to template structures (if you need a temporary workaround)...

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
  static void f(const T &v = T());
};

template<>
struct foo<std::string>
{
  static void f(const std::string &v = std::string())
  {
    std::cout << v;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, I can't check this in Visual Studio 2013 because I don't have it, but I hope it should work.

The downside here is that you should explicitly specify your type, it's no longer deducted

```
foo<std::string>::f()
foo<std::string>::f("Text")
```

My wild guess here would be adding like a wrapper function:

```
template<typename T>
void f_wrapper(const T &v = T())
{
  foo<T>::f(v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this!